# Can't profile in visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, profiling, diagnostics

When I try to profile in VS2017 15.3 I get the following message on screen:
"Microsoft Visual Studio encountered an error during your diagnostics session"
In the Diagnostics Hub below the following message appears:
"Failed to start trace session (0x800700b7)"

After some web searching I found the following way to get the logs of what went wrong:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61926/diagnostic-tools-not-working.html

So after trying that, this is the only line that is an error in the log file:

Error --- standardcollector.bridge.cpp --- Failed: StartCollection for profiling. HRESULT: 0xe1110018

I haven't been able to find any explaination for these error codes or what can I do with them.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to get a solution to this issue? I am using VS2017 15.5

Answer (score 6):

Do you have Process Explorer running? I found that Process Explorer interfered with the profiler somehow. I remember reading about how Windows 7 only allows one kernel level debugger at a time. Or something along those lines, sorry I'm a bit fuzzy there, but I just ran into this again and I remembered that closing Process Explorer fixes it. I imagine other similar programs might also interfere with the profiler.

Comment: Confirmed. I got the performance profiler to start after killing Process Explorer. (Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 7)